# React & asp.net - Importing react-bootstrap exception

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I did npm install on the folder with the react content. I'm not using webpack or bundler I pretty much went off this tutorial for setup, because I only need React as components https://reactjs.net/getting-started/aspnet.html and get this error

- $exception  {"Error while loading \"~/Scripts/react/Components/Progression/ProgressionTable.js\": SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier\r\n   at ProgressionTable.js:14:8 -> import Modal from 'react-bootstrap';"}    React.Exceptions.ReactScriptLoadException

so essentially it's complaining about the 'import' statement and it always does this for any import. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

In short import is not supported JS by the browsers so you need to use webpack/babel-loader to turn those import statements into JS that still works.

You would have to use a browser based loader like Require.JS to get your existing code to work here, but your better off having a look at enabling module import loading via Webpack/Babel.

To sum it up, having the right tooling in place will prevent import statements in your compile JS code that the browser has no idea how to handle.

Comment: Do you have any good resources on how to do this? I've been looking around for a bit with no luck. Always run into issues with one implementation or another. I'm using asp.net MVC 5

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5wTsHRsbIA something along these lines.  The packages should mostly be the same.

Comment: Thanks a ton I'll up score your response. Last question using this methodology how would I add a react component to cshtml file? Is it just the standard @html.React(<Component name>, new{})? I'm assuming I still need to add new React components to ReactConfig still? Or just after this is added everything should be gravy?

Comment: If you follow that course or others on my channel, I show how to setup babel, webpack and react.  Your UI should compile to one large JS file.   This includes react and everything else.  Than you just load that file and tell react which DOM element to bind to inside your cshtml file.  (most people use <div id='root'></div>

Comment: O hey I was actually following your tutorial before I posted, this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnFgGYooDCM&t=1169s. Unfortunately it didn't pan out for me and I was getting weird errors. I'll run through it again and see if it happens again just so I can inform you of exactly what happened.

Comment: I shot you an email. I got it working but now the issue is passing data from the Model is the cshtml file to the react component.